# Coffee script compiler keeps on throwing error 'TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, typeerror

I'm relatively new to coffee script.
Currently, when compiling a piece of coffee script (`coffee -c app.coffee`), I receive the following error (See below) even though '2' is nowhere in my code. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Here is the error:

```
`TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined
    at Lexer.exports.Lexer.Lexer.tokenize (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee script/lib/coffee-script/lexer.js:43:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:52:20)
    at Object.compile (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:34:19)
    at compileScript (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:232:33)
    at compilePath (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:174:14)
    at Object.exports.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:98:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee:7:41)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3`
```

Here is my code:

```
 express = require 'express'   
 path = require 'path'   
 favicon = require 'serve-favicon'   
 logger = require 'morgan'   
 cookieParser = require 'cookie-parser'   
 bodyParser = require 'body-parser'   
 clicolour = require 'cli-color'   
 fs = require "fs"   
 morgan = require "morgan"   

 passport = require 'passport'   
 passportlocal = require 'passport-local'   
 passporthttp = require 'passport-http'   

 mongoose = require 'mongoose'   
 MongoClient = require 'mongodb' .MongoClient  
 assert = require 'assert'   
 ObjectId = require 'mongodb'.ObjectID  

 connect = require "./libs/connect.js"   
 passportconfig = require "./libs/passport.js"   
 # wlogger = require "./libs/wlogger.js"   
 #  debuge = require "./libs/debug.js"   
 wlogger = require "./libs/logger"   

 routes = require './routes/index'   
 users = require './routes/users'   

 #debug = require 'debug'   'Web-OS:server'   
 http = require 'http'   
 https = require 'https'   

 app = express     

 bcrypt = require 'bcryptjs'   
 salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)   

 logFile = fs.createWriteStream('./logs/wos.log', {flags: 'a'})    

 # view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

 # uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
 #app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.use(logger({stream: logFile}));
app.use(logger('stream', wlogger.logger));
#app.use(require('morgan')({ "stream": wlogger.stream }));
wlogger.debug("Overriding 'Express' logger");
app.use(require("morgan")("combined", { "stream": wlogger.stream }));


 userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ->
  username: { type: String }
, email: String
, pwd: String

 exits = false  
 suser = mongoose.model('usersc', userSchema)   

app.use('/', routes)   
app.use('/users', users)  
app.use('passportconfig', passportconfig)   

# Setup HTTPS
# uncommitted after finding way to get certs
# options = {
  #key: fs.readFileSync  path.join  __dirname, 'cert/Web-OS-PRIVATE.key'  
  # This certificate should be a bundle containing your server certificate and any intermediates
  # cat certs/cert.pem certs/chain.pem > certs/server-bundle.pem
#, cert: fs.readFileSync  path.join  __dirname, 'cert/Web-OS-SIGNED.crt'  
  # ca only needs to be specified for peer-certificates
#, ca: [ fs.readFileSync  path.join  caCertsPath, 'my-root-ca.crt.pem'   ]
#, requestCert: false
#, rejectUnauthorized: true
#}  



 port = process.env.PORT || 8080  

app.listen(port, () ->
    clicolour.cyanBright  "webOS "  + clicolour.yellowBright  "startup "  + "Running on port " + port   
    clicolour.cyanBright  "webOS "  + clicolour.yellowBright  "startup "  + "The date and time is:", Date      
  clicolour.cyanBright  "webOS "  + clicolour.yellowBright  "startup "  + connect.connect  "Connect"    

)    
# HTTPS
httpsserver = https.createServer  options   
# Turn on HTTPS
# httpsserver.on  'request', app   
   # httpsserver.listen  6060, function     {
     #  console.log  clicolour.cyanBright  "webOS "  + clicolour.yellowBright  "HTTPS "  + "HTTPS Server Started " + port   
    #    console.log  clicolour.cyanBright  "webOS "  + clicolour.yellowBright  "HTTPS "  + "The date and time is:", Date      
    #onListening   
    #}    



app.on('error', onError())   
app.on('listening', onListening())   

normalizePort = (val) ->
   port = parseInt(val, 10)   

  if isNaN(port)
    # named pipe
    return val  

  if port >= 0  
    # port number
    return port  

  return false  

#
 # Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 #

onError = (error) ->
  if error.syscall !== 'listen'
    throw error  


   bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port  

  # handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch error.code  ->
    when 'EACCES' then
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges')   
      process.exit(1)   
      break  
    when 'EADDRINUSE' then
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use')   
      process.exit(1)   
      break  
    else
      throw error  


 # Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.

onListening = () ->
   addr = httpsserver.address     
   bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port  
  wlogger.debug('Listening on ' + bind)   



# catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) ->
   err = new Error  'Not Found'   
  err.status = 404  
  next  err   
)   

app.post('/login', (req, res)  ->
   # passportlocal.authenticate  'local'   
  res.redirect('/')  
)   

# error handlers

# development error handler
# will print stacktrace
if app.get('env'  === 'development')
  app.use((err, req, res, next) ->
    res.status(err.status || 500)   
    res.render('error.jade', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    })   
  )   


# production error handler
# no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use((err, req, res, next) ->
  res.status(err.status || 500)   
  res.render('error.jade', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  })   
)`
```

In case it helps, I made this code by taking the JavaScript version of this and adjusting it to be coffee script.

Here is the JavaScript I adjusted to be coffee-script:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var clicolour = require('cli-color');
var fs = require("fs");
var morgan = require("morgan");

var passport = require('passport');
var passportlocal = require('passport-local');
var passporthttp = require('passport-http');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var connect = require("./libs/connect.js");
var passportconfig = require("./libs/passport.js");
//var wlogger = require("./libs/wlogger.js");
// var debuge = require("./libs/debug.js");
var wlogger = require("./libs/logger");

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var debug = require('debug')('Web-OS:server');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

var app = express();

var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10); 

var logFile = fs.createWriteStream('./logs/wos.log', {flags: 'a'});


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.use(logger({stream: logFile}));
app.use(logger('stream', wlogger.logger));
//app.use(require('morgan')({ "stream": wlogger.stream }));
wlogger.debug("Overriding 'Express' logger");
app.use(require("morgan")("combined", { "stream": wlogger.stream }));

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String }
, email: String
, pwd: String
});
var exits = false;
var suser = mongoose.model('usersc', userSchema);

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('passportconfig', passportconfig);

// Setup HTTPS
// uncommitted after finding way to get certs
/** options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert/Web-OS-PRIVATE.key'))
  // This certificate should be a bundle containing your server certificate and any intermediates
  // cat certs/cert.pem certs/chain.pem > certs/server-bundle.pem
, cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert/Web-OS-SIGNED.crt'))
  // ca only needs to be specified for peer-certificates
//, ca: [ fs.readFileSync(path.join(caCertsPath, 'my-root-ca.crt.pem')) ]
, requestCert: false
, rejectUnauthorized: true
}; */



var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(clicolour.cyanBright("webOS ") + clicolour.yellowBright("startup ") + "Running on port " + port);
    console.log(clicolour.cyanBright("webOS ") + clicolour.yellowBright("startup ") + "The date and time is:", Date());
  console.log(clicolour.cyanBright("webOS ") + clicolour.yellowBright("startup ") + connect.connect("Connect"));

} );
// HTTPS
httpsserver = https.createServer(options);
// Turn on HTTPS
/** httpsserver.on('request', app);
    httpsserver.listen(6060, function () {
       console.log(clicolour.cyanBright("webOS ") + clicolour.yellowBright("HTTPS ") + "HTTPS Server Started " + port);
        console.log(clicolour.cyanBright("webOS ") + clicolour.yellowBright("HTTPS ") + "The date and time is:", Date());
    onListening()
    }); */



app.on('error', onError);
app.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = httpsserver.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  wlogger.debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
   // passportlocal.authenticate('local');
  res.redirect('/');
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error.jade', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error.jade', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

NB: This is my second question to tell me if you need more info.

Thanks

Comment: very hard to say... maybe you can try and make your code as small as possible which still shows the error.

Comment: Is that your actual indentation?

Comment: Your indentation may be screwing stuff up. Remember that coffee-script is whitespace sensitive

Comment: There are double spaces between tokens as well as trailing spaces. This may be triggering this open defect: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3906

Comment: Thanks! Removed all the indent and now it compiles successfully!